# How to set alpha property to image not to text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I use linearlayout to equally spread the space of view group. I set view group background as image and added alpha property to linearlayout. opacity is applied to all the views in view group.But I want alpha property should be applied to only background image  not to textview.Is there any way to do this in linearlayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/getCoffeeText"
    android:background="@drawable/coffee"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
     android:alpha="0.5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Order Coffee Here....!!!!"
        android:textColor="#D50000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60sp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="incrementCoffeeCount"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="45sp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#D50000"
            android:id="@+id/coffeeCount"
            />
        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="decrementCoffeeCount"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#D50000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="$0"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#D50000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130sp"
        android:id="@+id/price"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110sp"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

I want to do this in linearlayout not in Relativelayout.Anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FrameLayout` like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/coffee" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```